# Concatenate Drive and Directory of file path in C

Tags: c, filepath, strcat

I want to show file path in C program. I used `_splitpath()`function and there are five parameters. In these parameters, I concatenated `Drive` and `Dir` and concatenated again `Filename` and `Ext`using `strcat()`. In that case, the output of `strcat(Filename, Ext);`is correct but `strcat(Drive, Dir);`has an error. The error message shows me that the variable `Drive`has been corrupted. How can I concatenate `Drive` and `Dir`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{                            
    char szDrive[_MAX_DRIVE] = {0};
    char szDir[_MAX_DIR] = {0};
    char szFileName[_MAX_FNAME] = {0};
    char szExt[_MAX_EXT] = {0};
    char* pszFname = NULL;
    char* pszPname = NULL;

    _splitpath(argv[0], szDrive, szDir, szFileName, szExt);

    pszPname = strcat(szDrive, szDir);
    pszFname = strcat(szFileName, szExt);
    printf("Usage: %s fileName\n", pszFname);
    printf("EXE Path:%s", pszPname);
}
```

Comment: The Have you secure an area for that?

Comment: Would you prefer to debug it yourself without looking at the code? No? Neither can we, really ... It's probably string buffer errors that cause overwrites, but it's impossible to tell without seeing the code, naturally.

Comment: check `_MAX_DRIVE` : `_MAX_DRIVE` is probably 3, it's ,too small to bind to the directory name.

Comment: Yeah! `_MAX_DRIVE` is 3. It's a constant value, isn't it? So, how can I concatenate these two?

Comment: You should provide a separate area for storing the join results.

Comment: You mean another character pointer is needed to bind these two?

Comment: E.g `char pszPname[_MAX_DRIVE + _MAX_DIR] = {0};`//remove p

Comment: or `char szDrive[_MAX_DRIVE + _MAX_DIR] = {0};`

Comment: It's not OK! pszPname is corrupted.

Comment: Please be aware that strcat returns the first argument. The idea is to add some extra characters to the end of the string given as the first argument.